# How can I GZIP a string in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, gzip

I need to compress a string into GZIP format. I've looked at Apple's [compression framework documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/compressing_and_decompressing_data_with_buffer_compression?language=objc), but GZIP does not seem to be a supported algorithm.

My ultimate goal is to make a NSURLSessionData task with an urlRequest that has a GZIPPED postBody.

I know that the ZLIB algorithm is similar to GZIP, so is there some way to modify the results of ZLIB compression to get GZIP?

Comment: https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gzip is not an option for that compression framework. You can use zlib directly to compress and decompress gzip streams. zlib is already installed in iOS. [zlib.h](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html) is the zlib documentation. `deflateInit2()` will allow you select the gzip format for compression.

A comment to your question points to some [example code in Objective C](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP/blob/master/GZIP/Sources/NSData%2BGZIP.m).